# How to assign the value of div to unnamed textbox without id and class in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted to assign the value of div `.item` to empty textbox without name, ID and class. And on blur of the input again the `value` goes back to div id `.item`.

```
$(document).on("click", ".item", function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $(".input-active input[type='text']").val($(this).text()).focus();
});
$(document).on("blur", ".input-active input[type='text']", function() {
    $('.item').show();
    $('.item').text($(".input-active input[type='text']").val());
    $(".input-active input[type='text']").val('');
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gr4yy/40/)**

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/), *Get the immediately preceding sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the previous sibling only if it matches that selector.*

And,

[`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/), *Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector.*

```js
$(document).on("click", ".item", function() {
  $(this).hide();
  $(this).next("input[type='text']").val($(this).text()).focus();
});
$(document).on("blur", ".input-active input[type='text']", function() {
  $(this).prev('.item').show();
  $(this).prev('.item').text(this.value);
  $(this).val('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-active">
  <div class="item">editing text</div>
  <input type="text">
</div>
<div class="input-active">
  <div class="item">editing text</div>
  <input type="text">
</div>
<div class="input-active">
  <div class="item">editing text</div>
  <input type="text">
</div>
<div class="input-active">
  <div class="item">editing text</div>
  <input type="text">
</div>
<div class="input-active">
  <div class="item">editing text</div>
  <input type="text">
</div>
<div class="input-active">
  <div class="item">editing text</div>
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

### [**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/Gr4yy/41/)

Comment: This code is not flexible enough to handle repetitive divs. Have a look (http://jsfiddle.net/Gr4yy/40/)

Comment: @Bhawna, Did you provide enough information/context to provide better solution ? Do provide a fiddle where it fails...

Comment: Check the fiddle i sent you in comment

Answer (score 0):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click", ".item", function () {
      $(this).hide();
      $(".input-active input[type='text']").val($(this).text());
    });

    $(document).on("blur", ".input-active input[type='text']", function () {
     $('.item').show();
     $('.item').text($(this).val());
     $(this).val('');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input').bind('keyup keypress blur change focus click keydown', function (e,  param) {
var $this = $(this);
var value = $this.val();
}
```

The above code will provide the value for all the input controls with all the events....

Answer (score 0):

You need to go up to the parents using `closest` or `parents` to find related input/item and you should add condition to check empty case:

```
$(document).on("click", ".item", function() {
  $(this).hide();
  $(this).closest(".input-active").find("input[type='text']").val($(this).text()).focus();
});

$(document).on("blur", ".input-active input[type='text']", function() {
  var related_item = $(this).closest(".input-active").find('.item');

  if($(this).val()!=""){
    related_item.text($(this).val()).show();
    $(this).val('');
  }
});
```

Hope this helps.

---

### Snippet

```js
$(document).on("click", ".item", function() {
  $(this).hide();
  $(this).closest(".input-active").find("input[type='text']").val($(this).text()).focus();
});

$(document).on("blur", ".input-active input[type='text']", function() {
  var related_item = $(this).closest(".input-active").find('.item');

  if($(this).val()!=""){
    related_item.text($(this).val()).show();
    $(this).val('');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-active">
  <div class="item">editing text1</div>
  <input type="text"/>
</div>
<div class="input-active">
  <div class="item">editing text2</div>
  <input type="text"/>
</div>
<div class="input-active">
  <div class="item">editing text3</div>
  <input type="text"/>
</div>
```